# prolog length predefined list

Tags: list, prolog

In prolog,I have a rule that calculate the length of a list. I am wondering if my list is predefined what do I do?

for example, in the base I have

```
list1[1,2,3,4,3,5,8].

longueur([],0). 
longueur([_|Y],N) :- longueur(Y,M), N is M+1.
```

And in prolog I enter `longueur(list1,N).` I keep geting `false.`

Comment: `list1[1,2,3,4,3,5,8].` is not correct syntax and in particular does not mean that `list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Comment: but I don't get any error!

Comment: What distribution do you use? On SWI-Prolog, I get the following error, as expected: `ERROR: c:/test.pl:1:5: Syntax error: Operator expected`.

Comment: the same distribution as you. but if you put the list in () list1([1,2,3,4,3,5,8]). you don't get an error.

Comment: Well of course you don't but if you don't put the code that you use here how am I supposed to guess…

Comment: there is no code. like I told you, I want to calculate the length of a predefined list.The rule that I have (longueur) didn't help me becose I have to entre the list in SWI-Prolog before then I can calculate the length with (longueur). i want the list to be defined with (longueur) in the base. so what can I do?

Comment: I edited my answer, though I'm still unsure what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`longueur(list1,N).` is false because `list1` is not a list, and so does not match with any of the two rules of `longueur/2` that you wrote.

To get it to work, this is what you would do:

```
?- list1(X), longueur(X,L).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 8],
L = 7.
```

If you want `longueur/2` to work with `list1` as argument, and with `list1([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).` as fact, you should create a predicate like `longueur_depuis_atome/2`:

```
longueur_depuis_atome(A, L) :-
    call(A, X),
    longueur(X, L).
```

Then:

```
?- longueur_depuis_atome(list1,L).
L = 7.
```

Comment: now, I understand you. So in prolog I should put the list in my fact in a variable. 
thank you

Comment: It worked. but I did not understand longueur_depuis_atome. Can you please explain it more carefully to me.

Comment: @bttX `call(A, X)` results in the same thing as if you would write `A(X)` in the interpreter (but it works for any value of `A` obviously). So if `A = list1`, `call(A, X)` is the same as if you wrote `list1(X)`, which makes it so that `X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` through pattern matching. Then we call `longueur/2` because that's what we want…

Comment: so instead of putting always list1(X) before longueur(X,L) in swi-prolog, you put it in a rule?
Is call predefined in prolog just like member and append?

Comment: plus ou moins 1. That is, this technique is fine, but I doubt it is a good idea for starteurs.